# How to prevent Cmd-Q from typing "q" in the new foreground app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings, applications

My background app (the one that gets activated when the current app quits) is some text editor. When I use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut to quit it and immediately afterwards let go of **only** the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key, the text editor types a `q` character.

Of course I normally don't intentionally keep <kbd>Q</kbd> pressed. While using the Quartz keyboard layout I never even noticed this, but when I changed to the Dvorak layout, I occasionally saw this happen (probably because of the [location of <kbd>Q</kbd> on the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n1AR.png)). It happens with both layouts though.

I'm pretty sure it's *not* a problem with specifically my Mac (EDIT: It only happens with my **Logitech** keyboard). It's quiet annoying, especially while coding since I quit the developing app a lot and the `q` in my source code makes it not compile anymore.

My questions are:

1. <s>Does this only happen on my Mac? Can someone test this?</s> It only happens with the Logitech keyboard.
2. **How can I prevent this from happening?** (other than always paying attention to let go of <kbd>Q</kbd> before <kbd>Cmd</kbd>)
3. Why is this even happening? I don't think it's supposed to be like this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Tested and mine doesn't do this.
2. Try to turn **off** key repeat: (mine below is not off)

[image]

3. Maybe you have a non-Apple keyboard with anti-ghosting?

Comment: Ahh yes! It's the Logitech keyboard that's doing it! I didn't even think about that. I'll look up anti-ghosting now I guess

Comment: Cool np, let us know! :)

Comment: So the Apple keyboard works?

Comment: Yes, the Apple keyboard works. I couldn't find anything else regarding this problem though, no idea how to solve it. I'm probably gonna buy a new keyboard soon anyways though.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem, and can confirm that it only seems to happen when I'm using my Logitech keyboard.  I fiddled with lots of keyboard settings, but none of them stopped the errant "q" from happening.  But I've found a (poor) solution that *does* work:

**Solution:**
Whenever you press `cmd+q`, make sure you release the `q` key *before* releasing the `cmd` key.  As long as you release the keys in this order, the "`q`" character won't be sent to the new foreground app.